# Did the owner of Stack Overflow ask coding questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, jeff-atwood

I was wondering if Stack Overflow owner "Jeff Atwood" was asking questions on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange about coding?

What is his Stack Overflow username?

Or if you downvoted his question, does he have the right to ban the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood

Comment: He used to do [house visits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/158100) ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be no surprise that his user ID is `1`, and even if it was, you found the [jeff-atwood](/questions/tagged/jeff-atwood) tag and his profile is linked to in the [tag information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/jeff-atwood/info). He asked [16 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=questions) on Stack Overflow, and perhaps more programming questions on other Stack Exchange sites.

[image]

Jeff visits the site but isn't really active here anymore, and does not have the power to ban you. (He does have the power to downvote, but that holds for everybody with more than 100/125 reputation.)

Comment: If you want a full overview of all questions and answers he posted you can check out his network profile here: https://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=top